# Confused with the format - sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb, ios5

I'm still learning in iOS application development.
What's the difference between .sqlite and .db in using sqlite database?
Which is the right one to use?

My concern is that FMDB just uses ".db" file. What sqlite manager would I use to produce ".db" file?
On the other hand, the sqlite manager of firefox produces ".sqlite" which I guess FMDB do not recognize.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter- you don't even need an extension if you don't want one.  It's the format of the file that matters.  If it's an sqlite file, FMDB should be able to read it.

Comment: Thanks! I want to use the ".db" file in my xcode project. After dragging the db into my project and including this statement  FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"vb.db"]; it doesn't seem to work. Can you site what's wrong?

Comment: I got it already. I have solved the connection using this code: NSString *dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vb" ofType:@"db"]; .